# Angular | Cannot read property 'XXX' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, properties, model

I used 2 model.ts

**profile.model.ts**

```
export interface Profile {
    username: string;
    nickname: string;
    image: string;
  }
```

'comment.model.ts' uses 'profile.model.ts'.

**comment.model.ts**

```
import { Profile } from '.';

export interface Comment {
  author: Profile;
  content: string;
  creatat?: Date;
}
```

**comment.component.ts**

```
...
export class CommentComponent implements DoCheck {
  ...
  content: string;      // Get value from ngModel in comment.component.html
  comments: Comment;    // comment.model.ts
}
...

  addComment() {
    this.comments.author.nickname = 'Test Nickname';
    this.comments = {
      content: this.content
    };
    ...
  }
```

When I run addComment(), I get the following error.

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'author' of undefined

What is the problem?

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your `comments` property. Currently you have only set the type of it - `Comment`.

Because properties of `Profile` are not *optional* you need explicitly assign them `null`s.

```
comments: Comment = { 
   author: {  
      username: null,
      nickname: null,
      image: null,
   }, 
   content: null 
}
```

Or you can make them optional adding `?` after the names of the properties'.

```
export interface Profile {
    username?: string;
    nickname?: string;
    image?: string;
}
```

...

```
export interface Comment {
  author?: Profile;
  content?: string;
  creatat?: Date;
}
```

and initialize like

```
comments: Comment = { 
   author: { } 
}
```